# How to change Tomboy's monospaced font (on Windows)?

Tags: windows, fonts, tomboy

I'm running [Tomboy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/) on Windows, and altough it lets me change "the font", that setting only affects the main font, while the monospaced font is preset to Courier New.

Courier New really hurts my eyes badly, like it was some Papyrus-ComicSans half-breed. I want to set it to [Ubuntu Mono](http://font.ubuntu.com/). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic "monospace" font seems to be set in the source code, but it's not explicitely asking for Courier New. I don't know where it pulls that default from.

Of course a custom-built `fixedWidth.dll` would fix this, but it's a sucky solution. Still looking for a better idea.

---

**Update:** You know what, duck it. Courier New angers me so much that I grabbed Tomboy's source code, modified it, and recompiled. It went fairly straightforward in fact, but if you're real lazy, here's the goodies:

[Custom dll that's hardcoded to Ubuntu Mono (also includes Consolas version for convenience)](http://sdrv.ms/Zl5UdK).